# Seeking Multiple-Form Table example in django

Tags: django, forms, model

I am trying to build a complex table in django that can combine multiple model elements into a single html page.  I am finding a few examples on how to build a page for a single model element.  Filemaker delivers this capability, but I can't stomach porting this into Filemaker.  I'd like to use django if at all possible.

For example puposes, I built a car-sales model.  Everyone pretty much understands multiple fields as it relates to buying a car.  The actual model isn't so clean.  In the example model, the user is the sales person.  When the user logs in they see their customer screen.  Rather than making the user flip through multiple pages, I'm trying to fit lots of related data onto one page.

Is it possible to build a single form to do this?  Does django offer anything
to make this easier than building lots of custom html forms?  Is anyone aware of a similar example?

-----------my layout--------------

```
<table>
  <tr><td> Top Left: Basic Customer info </td>
      <td> Top Right: Wish List info.  They want, but probably can't buy. </td>
      <td rowspan=2> A great big scrollable list of all customers </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Bottom Left: Sales Person info about himself </td>
      <td>Bottom Right: A big notes section from the selected customer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

-----------my model--------------

```
# Bottom Left Panel
class SalesPersonProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
  company = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  addr = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
  zipCode = models.CharField(max_length=8)

# Top Left Panel Information
# Also a list of this stuff that goes in the extreme right
class Customer(models.Model):
  salesPerson = models.ForeignKey(User, editable = False) 
  lastName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
  zip = models.CharField(max_length=8)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')

  # BOTTOM RIGHT - A great big multi-line notes field
  notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

#  Top Right Info
class WishList(models.Model):
  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, unique=True)
  dtg = models.DateTimeField('Date Added')
  carType = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CAR_TYPE)
  year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
  make = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  miles = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

try create one form with all fields you need and then ovveride save,validate etc form methods